# instant insert/edit

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, sql

I've seen multiple websites on the web where they allow you to manipulate data. (i.e. Insert records, delete records, edit records).
The cool thing I've noticed is that when you click remove button, the item removes instantly from the grid. and then it asynchronously goes to a database and removes record from there without bothering a user.
For example in a regular asp.net application if you're using gridview you need to wait until database operation is complete, because gridview is a databound control.  If you use update panel you still see item in grid until DataBind event fires again.

Question: is there any js/.net library that will allow me to add such a functionality to the project out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `WebMethod` on server side + `Ajax` calls on client side (using `jQuery` for example).

Comment: Any examples/links of how I can do this in asp.net would be great.

Comment: I don't have any code on hand. Here is a simple example http://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can you Client Side Grid Like JQGrid. http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. For loading and editing data you can use Web method or web Services. You can also use ASP.net MVC .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do.You have web method that read your data from your source such as database.
You can call this method using Ajax and you can bind ajax response to gridview
Here is example [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775585/Bind-Gridview-using-AJAX)